# GTK4. C language. VS code

Tags: c, gtk4

I want to connect gtk4, VS Code sees ther, but displays

```
code.c:3:10: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
    3 | #include <gtk/gtk.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

**tasks.json:**

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "-IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/gtk-4.0"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

**c_cpp_properties.json:**

```json
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "windows-gcc-x64",
      "includePath": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**",
        "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/gtk-4.0",
        "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/glib-2.0",
        "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/glib-2.0/include",
        "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/pango-1.0",
        "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/harfbuzz",
        "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/cairo",
        "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0",
        "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/atk-1.0",
        "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/graphene-1.0",
        "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/graphene-1.0/include"
      ],
      "compilerPath": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe",
      "cStandard": "${default}",
      "cppStandard": "${default}",
      "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64",
      "compilerArgs": [
        ""
      ]
    }
  ],
  "version": 4
}
```

Initially, in **c_cpp_properties.json**, the includePath was `"${workspaceFolder}/**"`, then correcting errors, I added new ones and it turned out as in the photo above. After that, apart from the fact that this file cannot be found, it does not show anything else.

Comment: Add `"C:/msys64/mingw64/include"` as an include path. `<gtk/gtk.h>`  is a subdirectory of the normal `include` folder. When you omit `"C:/msys64/mingw64/include"` , I'm not sure VS code has any way of knowing that is the normal include folder.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of error messages, copy&paste the text and put it here. Can you see on the terminal all the options that are passed to gcc?

Comment: If I look at `tasks.json`, it seems that it passes `-IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/gtk-4.0` to gcc. Does the directory `C:/msys64/mingw64/include/gtk-4.0/gtk` exists?

Comment: Yes, it does. Also even when I write include, VS Code shows what is inside this folder

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a lot, but this may have helped. I changed the files and it worked.

**tasks.json:**

```json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "-IC:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\gtk-4.0",
                "-IC:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\glib-2.0",
                "-IC:\\msys64\\mingw64\\lib\\glib-2.0\\include",
                "-IC:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\cairo",
                "-IC:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\pango-1.0",
                "-IC:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\harfbuzz",
                "-IC:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\gdk-pixbuf-2.0",
                "-IC:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\graphene-1.0",
                "-IC:\\msys64\\mingw64\\lib\\graphene-1.0\\include",
                "-lgtk-4",
                "-lgdk_pixbuf-2.0",
                "-lgio-2.0",
                "-lgobject-2.0",
                "-lglib-2.0"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

**c_cpp_properties.json:**

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "windows-gcc-x64",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\gtk-4.0",
                "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\glib-2.0",
                "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\lib\\glib-2.0\\include",
                "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\cairo",
                "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\pango-1.0",
                "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\harfbuzz",
                "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\gdk-pixbuf-2.0",
                "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\graphene-1.0",
                "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\lib\\graphene-1.0\\include"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "${default}",
            "cppStandard": "${default}",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64",
            "compilerArgs": [
                "-mfpmath=sse",
                "-msse",
                "-msse2"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```